# how to have xsp-responsive-modal centered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I have a very long XPage and use dialog boxes on multiple locations on it. I note that the xp:dialogbox control requires to navigate up to the xpage in order to be able to read it.

Is it possible to have it displayed (sometimes) centered?

The content (height) of the dialogs differ for each case?

Answer (score 0):

With a bootstrap theme, the height from the top is managed via CSS, as a top margin. You can override that in your application-level stylesheet and possibly on each dialog. I don't think you can calculate the height of the dialog on-the-fly, but you should be able to identify the page height and calculate based on the approximate height you expect the dialog to be. I'm not sure if the browser will repaint if the user changes the height of the browser window, but if that is the case that's a browser restriction, not an XPages one.

Comment: the xsp-responsive-modal class is added which have properties. I tried a pure CSS approach like: .modal {
  max-height: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
} but then the header of the modal disappears initially